# Zero-Inflated Distributions

Tags: r, distribution

```
library(pscl)
data("bioChemists")
bioChemists
summary(bioChemists)

###TEST FOR ZERO-INFLATED on bioChemists data in pscl package
#Poisson Distribution and Zero-Inflated Poisson Distribution
glm_pois <- glm(art ~ ., data = bioChemists, family = poisson)
zip <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | ., data = bioChemists)
vuong(glm_pois, zip)


#Negative Binomial distribution and zero inflated negative binomial distribution 
glm_nb <- MASS::glm.nb(art ~ ., data=bioChemists)
zinb <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | ., data = bioChemists, dist = "negbin")
vuong(glm_nb, zinb)
```

How do I test for other distributions like the Conway-Maxwell Poisson Distribution, Poisson Inverse Gaussian and Poisson-Lindley Distribution?